# Function to count number of digits in string

Tags: php, counting, digits

I was looking for a quick PHP function that, given a string, would count the number of numerical characters (i.e. digits) in that string. I couldn't find one, is there a function to do this?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This can easily be accomplished with a regular expression.

```
function countDigits( $str )
{
    return preg_match_all( "/[0-9]/", $str );
}
```

The function will return the amount of times the pattern was found, which in this case is any digit.

Comment: mind you that the third parameter only is optional since 5.4, so to be sure best add a value to receive the matches. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: How can I do if I only want to count many times is repeated the number 4?

Comment: @ras212 Replace [0-9] with 4.

Answer (score 7):

first [split your string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php), next [filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) the result to [only include numeric](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) chars and then simply [count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) the resulting elements.

```
<?php 

$text="12aap33";
print count(array_filter(str_split($text),'is_numeric'));
```

edit: added a benchmark
out of curiosity: (loop of 1000000 of above string and routines)

preg_based.php is overv's preg_match_all solution

```
harald@Midians_Gate:~$ time php filter_based.php 

real    0m20.147s
user    0m15.545s
sys     0m3.956s

harald@Midians_Gate:~$ time php preg_based.php 

real    0m9.832s
user    0m8.313s
sys     0m1.224s
```

the regular expression is clearly superior. :)

Comment: Thanks for running the numbers (pun intended) on this one.

Answer (score 4):

For PHP < 5.4:

```
function countDigits( $str )
{
    return count(preg_grep('~^[0-9]$~', str_split($str)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function goes through the given string and checks each character to see if it is numeric. If it is, it increments the number of digits, then returns it at the end.

```
function countDigits($str) {
    $noDigits=0;
    for ($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++) {
        if (is_numeric($str{$i})) $noDigits++;
    }
    return $noDigits;
}
```