# PHP Check for Multiple Numbers in a Row in a String

Tags: php

I want to check if users are putting their phone number into a string.

Just need to check for 6 numbers (digits) in a row.

What is the best way to do this in PHP?

Example String:

`blah blah553376and blah`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because "how do I do this arbitrary thing" is not a real question.

Comment: Legit question IMO. Helpful is also https://stackoverflow.com/q/11023753/1066234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$str = "blah blah553376and blah";
preg_match('!\d+!', $str, $matches);//You can use preg_match('!\d{6,}!', $str, $matches); also
if(isset($matches[0]) && is_numeric($matches[0]) && strlen(trim($matches[0])) >= 6){
  echo $matches[0];
}
```

Comment: Why not just `\d{6,}`?

Comment: let them try something first .. the user has not shown a single piece of code .. :-/

Comment: But that doesn't make my answer incorrect @SyedQarib. If the question needs to be improved then you can add a comment or flag it or once you have earned enough reputation you can vote to close the question

Comment: thanks so much - I'll write a better question next time... appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome @Adam..:-) Next time when you post a question please show your efforts also

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃: I haven't said that your answer is incorrect .. what was incorrect I pointed that out .. on the question itself the first comment is 'what have you tried so far' .. so let them try first .. don't do spoon feeding ..

Comment: I have pointed that in my comment to add what the op have tried

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this problem:

1. The regex solution, as pointed out by some others.  I'm in no way a regex expert, but this seems to work:

   ```
   $input_line="blah blah553376and blah";
   $regex_line="/([a-z 0-9]*)([0-9]{6})([a-z 0-9]*)/i";
   $output_array=Array();
   preg_match($regex_line, $input_line, $output_array);
   if($output_array[2])
   {
       echo("number is:  ". $output_array[2]);
   }
   else
   {
       echo("number not found");
   }
   ```
2. The exhaustive iteration method:

   ```
   $input_line="blah blah553376and blah";

   $output_string="";
   for($i=0; $i<strlen($input_line);$i++)
   {
       $current_character = substr($input_line,$i,1);
       if(is_numeric ( $current_character ))
       {
           $output_string .= $current_character;
       }
       else
       {
           //reset output
           $output_string="";
       }

       if(strlen($output_string) >=6)
       {
           //bail out if requirements are met.
           break;
       }
   }
   if($output_string)
   {
       echo("number is:  " . $output_string);
   }
   else
   {
       echo("number not found");
   }
   ```
3. I'm sure there are other better ways, but above are just two simple ways off the top of my head to approach this.