# How do you find the length of a variable with letters, numbers and symbols in html and php?

Tags: php, html, variables

If, for example, a person wants their username to be GreenApples-72, how do you count the number of letters, numbers and symbols in the username and add them up?

```
        if((($_POST['username'])<'2'))    //if the username length is less than 2.
        {
            echo('Your username has fewer than 2 characters');
        }
```

This is my code so far, this is the checking stage of the code. I'm not sure on how to code this part.

Comment: Take a look on `strlen` function on [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: Did you try to search at least ?

Comment: Is it correct that your desired result is the amount of chars and numbers, not the length of the string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function to count number of digits in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023753/function-to-count-number-of-digits-in-string)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php):

```
echo strlen("GreenApples-72"); // echoes 14
```

Comment: @crypticous Could you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Use **strlen()** function in php to count the length of the variable. Use the code below to count the length of the variable

```
if(strlen($_POST['username'])<'2')    //if the username length is less than 2.
        {
            echo('Your username has fewer than 2 characters');
        }
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you allow all characters at this stage (and it seems you do), you should use multibyte function `mb_strlen()` to check string length:

```
 mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); // set utf-8 encoding for all mb_ functions

 if(mb_strlen($_POST['username'])<'2')    //if the username length is less than 2.
 {
    echo('Your username has fewer than 2 characters');
 }
```

`strlen` won't be good enough in this case because:

```
echo strlen('ą'); // will return 2

echo mb_strlen('ą','UTF-8'); // will return 1
```